# CSS linear gradient not working on iOS when combined with image url in background property

Tags: ios, css, background, linear-gradients

I'm using combination of linear-gradient and image url as a background on a page. This all works well on both desktop and mobile (android only) but it  breaks for iOS (iPhone and iPad, tested on iOS 12) and displays only one of the gradient colors.
Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.green-background-image {
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 139, 243, 0.9),rgba(72, 177, 0, 0.6)), url(background-min.jpg);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 139, 243, 0.9), rgba(72, 177, 0, 0.6)), url(background-min.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color:#498ca7;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

I have added the browser prefix for the `webkit` but this didn't made any difference.

Here are some screenshots on both case (working and not working)
[image: Android screenshot]  [image: iOS screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be issue with the `background-attachment` property. After I added `background-attachment: scroll;` for mobile screen size the problem was solved.

**EDIT**

A bit better solution I found somewhere (sorry can't find again the link) is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 786px){

    .green-background-image {
        background-image: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: inherit;
        background-position: inherit;
        background-size: inherit;
        background-position-y: auto;
    }

    .green-background-image{
        content:"";
        background-color: RGB(6, 134, 238);
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        height:100vh;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        z-index:-1;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg,rgb(0, 139, 243),rgba(72,177,0,0.63)),url(background-min.jpg);
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

}
```